# Composer zend1 framework with directory structure?

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

Is it possible to install zend 1 framework with composer and directory structure? I found the way to install only framework into vendor folder, but this is without directory structure...

Without file structure my composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "name": "zend1/zend-composer",
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Maximilian",
            "email": "maxi@website.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly installed zend 1 using composer.
To get a new project, you need to run:

**./vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/bin/zf.sh create project myprojectname**

in a terminal, at the folder installed,

and also then you need to edit **myprojectname/public/index.php**

- Remove **require_once 'Zend/Application.php';**
- Add in its place **require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';**

This will enable you to load the Zend library through the composer autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, installing zf1 with composer means installing the ZF1 library with composer (and therefore remove /library/Zend from the project. You need to recreate the structure on your own.

For the rest of the structure, nothing changes except:

- `include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` in `public/index.php`
- not having `library/Zend'
- remove the `set_include_path` from `public/index.php`

That's it.